# How to VBA to select a pair of sheets and copy them to a new wb?

Tags: excel, macros, vba

'First-timer here, so thanks for your patience!
I have a workbook with multiple sheets, and I need to:

1)Select pairs of worksheets (index and index +1)

2)Copy them into a new workbook

3)Rename the sheets with whatever label is in a referenced cell (such as A1)

4)Then repeat for every pair of sheets in the workbook (dozens of pairs)

Since I am very new to vba (only took one class), I am easily confused.  The only part I have so far is referencing cell A1 to rename the sheet to whatever text string is in that cell.  I can't figure out the rest of it.  I'm thinking it has something to do with worksheet.index or worksheets(index) and some kind of loop where index adds 2 and activates that sheet and the next one before copying: sheets 1 and 2, then sheets 3 and 4, etc.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate() 
 Dim s As String 
 s = "sheet 1" 
 If Range("A1").Value <> "" Then 
     s = Range("A1").Value 
 End If 
 ActiveSheet.Name = s 
 End Sub
```

The way I understand it, cell A1 has to be checked to be sure it's not null because you can't name a  sheet with a null value.  The usage and syntax on the rest of it is quite beyond me at this point, but I really want to learn and eventually become a contributing member of this community.  I'm brand new at my job and only working part-time, so bringing a solution to my boss might mean me becoming permanent.  Therefore, a BIG, BIG THANKS!!!

Comment: Are these indexed sheets named in a consistent fashion? You would need to write some code that loops through all the available sheets in a workbook - or opens the workbook with the sheets - identifies worksheet with the content you want to copy into. Unless these sheets are named it a consistent fashion, you may have problems.

Comment: Yes, sheets are all named consistently with g/l account number:  xx-xxxx-xxxx-xx.  Isn't there some sort of command (method?), though, that will select sheets based on their INDEX number (1,2,3,etc.)?

Comment: You would have to create one, however if there is consistency with the names of the sheets you can do it

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim s As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsi As Worksheet

Set wsi = Sheets("Sheet4")' You need to create a name for the sheet to paste into

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("A1")) and ws.name = "INDEXCOPY" Then
     ws.Name = ws.Range("A1").Value
     ws.Range("A1:" & ws.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address).Copy _
     Destination:=wsi.Range("A1")
End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

This code will get you started, however, you need a way to distinguish between an index sheet you want to copy from, versus an index sheet you want to copy to. You would need to add an additional if then statement, see comment above. I would look here - http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win006.htm

Comment: Thanks so much, @Lowpar!  I will give this some thought and see what I am able to figure out.  I will also check out the link you provided.  Just to be sure I understand what code is doing...

Comment: Set wsi = Sheets("Sheet4") copies the sheet IN PLACE OF 'Sheet4' or will it NAME it 'Sheet4'? Also, I don't understand the ws.name = INDEXCOPY arg.  Does that just take the fist sheet?  Module says take range A1 to last cell (xlCellTypeLastCell).Address) and .copy it, puts into the wsi worksheet starting at Range("A1"), correct?  How to also copy the INDEX = 2 sheet at same time into the SAME new wb as sheet1.  So, it's really For Each PAIR, if that is possible.  Then, the NEXT will copy Sheets 3 and 4 to a NEW wb; Sheets 5 and 6 to NEW, etc.

Comment: I have been researching but am not ready post any answer or further comment at this time due to getting easily confused (especially trying to figure out the INDEX part).  Ha!

Comment: Could you post your current code, maybe I could help and you could edit the answer after

Comment: I will try and sort out the pieces that have, see which parts work, then post.  This question has been pushed to a back burner for the moment due to more pressing matters.  I may have to go another cycle of manually processing before I get this figured out.  Please stay tuned!